# Self complementing Codes

Tags: code

This statement was deemed true:
**Given any self-complementing decimal code scheme, if we know the codes for the number 283, then we can deduce the codes for 671.**

I wanna know why. I took Excess-3 BCD as the self complementing code:

```
0-0011
1-0100
2-0101
3-0110
4-0111
5-1000
6-1001
7-1010
8-1011
9-1100

So 283 = 0101 1011 0110
   671 = 1001 1010 0011
```

So why is the statement as it is as 283-ex3 is not a 1s complement of 671-ex3?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about maths.

Comment: Its from a module digital logic...Maybe you should reconsider what you just said.

Comment: @RStyle Maybe you should be grateful for any feedback being a noob in here. Anyway, this is one of those disputable topics. IMO it's an alright question for EE, SO and Math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A code is said to be self-complementary if the code for 9’s
complement of N i.e. 9-N can be obtained by interchanging all 0s
and 1s." (This answers the why question)

Finding the complement of the digits:

```
9-2=7 , since 2 is 0101, then 7 is 1010
9-8=1 , since 8 is 1011, then 1 is 0100
9-3=6 , since 3 is 0110, then 6 is 1001
```

With this you know the digits 2,8,3,7,1,6 and can make any permutation with them you like.

As an addition, I believe if you don't know if the number is LSB first or MSB first, you can only know the complement of 8 (there are two options for the others).

Answer (score 0):

What I think is, from 283 you can get the code for its 9's complement, *ie.,* 716. (that is what you actually calculated above)

So you can get the code for 671 just by rotating it right by 4 bit positions.

OR

You can get the code for 671 from 328 which is the 4-bit right shifted version of 283.